# Getting my wall posts or friends from Facebook - lists are empty

Tags: python, windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I performed following:

1. installed 2 kinds of the Facebook APIs: *pip install facebook* and *pip install fb*
2. Went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/, registered my app and got **User Token** (some long string, used currently as hardcoded in the code, I'll change it later)
3. Created the following code (please see comments what and how works or doesn't:

   ```
   import re
   import urllib2
   import requests
   import facebook
   import fb


   token="User Token"
   graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
   profile = graph.get_object("me")   #POSITIVE: I can get profile info
   friends = graph.get_connections('me', "friends")  #POSITIVE: I can get real friends count, NEGATIVE - the list itself is empty
   posts = graph.get_connections('me', "posts")  #NEGATIVE - the list itself is empty, no count is returned, as in "friends" case
   feed= graph.get_connections('me', "feed")  #NEGATIVE - the list itself is empty, no count is returned, as in "friends" case

   fb1=fb.graph.api(token)
   profile = fb1.get_object(cat='single', id="me")  #NEGATIVE - error in given parameters
   ```

To be sure I used also https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer with the same token and got the same results:

```
GET me\friends:
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 575
  },
}

GET me\feed:
{
  "data": [
  ],
}
```

Why the returned lists are empty?

Thanks!

Update: I found that I have no permissions, only those. How to get more? and why with permission "friends" I can't see info about them, but only total number of them?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ],
}
```

**Resolved**: I found where the problem! I didn't get app token with all permissions. Perform the following:

1. Go to the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
2. Choose your APP name (my is lj_for_me in attached image)
3. Press "Get User Token" and check all boxes (or what you really need).

Now you APP will have permission to get post and photos and etc from **YOUR** FB account. For getting the same from other users accounts you need to get such permission from FB (as far as I understood, but I did not enter too deep into this subject)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too, for privacy reasons. You only get the `total_count` if none of your friends authorized the App.

Access to wall posts is possible with the `user_posts` permission, btw.

Comment: I found were was problem, please see my solution in updated post

Comment: correction: my solution resolve only part to get my posts, not friends info, but I actually don't need it, it was just for attempt to use API

Comment: now that is a VERY bad idea, to get "all permissions" for one task. the official docs tell you exactly which permission you need for which api call, only use that one.

Comment: i´ve added the info to my answer